# How to get the status of tests in my file using hound?

Tags: elixir, ex-unit, hound

ExUnit provides some methods to get test result. I am not sure how to use it https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.Test.html and https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.Formatter.html.

I have multiple tests in a file. How can I generate results at the end like Test name and Status ?

I am writing test using hound.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In the first place, one can use [`ExUnit.after_suite/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.html#after_suite/1) for this purpose. The finest tuning might be done with introducing your own formatter and passing it to [`ExUnit.configure/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.html#configure/1) before a call to `ExUnit.start()`. Somewhat like the below (adjust to your needs.)

```rb
defmodule MyApp.CLIFormatter do
  @moduledoc false
  use GenServer

  def init(opts), do: {:ok, opts}

  def handle_cast({:suite_started, _opts}, config) do
    IO.puts("Started")
    {:noreply, config}
  end

  def handle_cast({:suite_finished, run_us, load_us}, config) do
    IO.inspect(
      {{:suite_finished, run_us, load_us}, config},
      label: "Finished")
    {:noreply, config}
  end

  def handle_cast(_, config), do: {:noreply, config}
end

ExUnit.configure(formatters: [ExUnit.CLIFormatter, MyApp.CLIFormatter])

ExUnit.start()
```